# Zombie process (kill both child and parent process)

Tags: bash, scripts, process, zombie

Question: I want to make sure that both child and parent process are killed and echo if successful or not. I'm new on using bash script and having issue with my output.

```
#!/bin/bash
for p in $(ps jauxww | grep Z | grep -v PID | awk '{print $3}'); do
for everyone in $(ps auxw | grep $p | grep cron | awk '{print $2}');do
kill -9 $everyone;
echo(Detected zombie process:"$PID". "$usr": . Successfully Killed);
else
echo (Detected zombie process:"$PID".  "$usr": . Could not kill);
done;
done;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't kill a Zombie, its already dead. It is just talking an entry in the process table before the parent process do `wait(2)` to read it's exit status.

On a different note, to kill the parent process of any process (including Zombie), you can easily use a combination of commands `ps` and `kill`:

```
ps -p <pid> -o ppid=
```

will give use the PPID (Parent Process ID) of the process having PID (Process ID) `<pid>`.

So for example, to find the PPID of process having PID `2345`:

```
ps -p 2345 -o ppid=
```

You can pass it to `kill` using command substitution `$()`:

```
kill "$(ps -p 2345 -o ppid=)"
```

---

On the other hand to kill a process using its PPID, use `pkill`:

```
pkill -P <PPID>
```

For example to kill the process having PPID `1234`:

```
pkill -P 1234
```

---

Also unless absolutely necessary do not use `SIGKILL` (`kill -9`) as it does not let the process to do any cleanup and might result in unwanted effects.

Comment: I want the script to do the kill process instead of running the command's to kill the process

Comment: @user3613649 Its more cleaner and simpler than running a script for this. If you want you can just create a script using the commands.

Comment: An example to echo result in a log file                                                                                           for pid in $(ps axo pid=,stat= | awk '$2~/^Z/ { print $1 }') ; do
 kill "$(ps -p -o ppid=)"
    echo echo (Detected zombie process:"$PID". "$usr": . Successfully Killed);
    else 
    echo (Detected zombie process:"$PID".  "$usr": . Could not kill);
done

Comment: @user3613649 You forgot to put the `pid`: `kill "$(ps -p "$pid" -o ppid=)"` ..Also correct your wording as you can't (aren't) killing a zombie but its parent..

Comment: Thanks.                                                                                   for pid in $(ps axo pid=,stat= | awk '$2~/^Z/ { print $1 }') ; do
 pid: kill "$(ps -p "$pid" -o ppid=)"
    echo (Detected zombie process:"$PID". "$user": . Successful);
    else 
    echo (Detected zombie process:"$PID".  "$user": . not successful);
done